# Sum multiple dataframe columns based on a condition

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a python dataframe with 30 columns,
I would like to add new column and set it to be the sum only the columns that equal to 1 from the last 10 columns (20:30)

How can I do that ?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide some sample data, the intended output and what you've tried so far.

Comment: Python doesn't have dataframes. You probably have a _pandas_ dataframe. If so, please add the [tag:pandas] tag to your question.